# How to restrict internet access to AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have AWS accounts created and managed using control tower service.

The requirement is to restrict internet access from lambda even it is not attached to any VPC.

By default lambda functions can connect to internet if it is not connected to any VPC.

How do we enforce restricting internet access to users using lambda functions ?

Comment: Not possible, unless you put it in a VPC.

Comment: It's **lambda** - yes, "b" before "d" - not "lamda" ...

Comment: same for me, i didnt configured any VPC in my account but i can acess internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have addressed this requirement by creating a service control policy with below statements and attached to the OU.

It enforces the users to select a VPC, subnet and security group while creating/updating the lambda function. With this you can make sure the lambda functions are always under your VPC.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-conditions

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "EnforceVPCFunction",
      "Action": [
          "lambda:CreateFunction",
          "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
       ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
           "lambda:VpcIds": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Refer the above AWS documentation to find the policy statements to enable restriction at different levels like subnet, Security group and VPC.

Comment: It still allows to create a VPC with Internet Gateway, and run Lambda in it. Wasn't that also a concern?

Comment: We already have another SCP that restrict creation of VPC with Internet Gateway. So, here I was looking how to enforce a lambda function creation with VPC enabling only.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda is always in a VPC,just when you don't specify a VPC it's assigned to default one which has internet access configured.

Create a new VPC, by default it won't have internet access. And assign your functions to it.

Comment: can this restriction achieve by any service control policy at organization level ?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question. I guess you could disallow deployment to default VPC on the organization and also block the Internet Gateway, so the newly created VPC won't have internet access